# Access denied issue with NEW-PSDrive commandlet

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, azure-devops

I have two machines: *Machine A*(Windows Server 2012 R2) and *Machine B.*(Windows 10)

We use Machine A to host an ASP.NET Web application, Machine B is my development machine

Both *A* and *B* are behind a corporate firewall and are joined to an Active Directory domain.

When I try to mount a PS drive on Machine B pointing to a location on machine A with the following command:

```
New-PSDrive "Kablam" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\A\F$\Install -Credential $cred
```

I get an access denied Error:

```
New-PSDrive : Access is denied
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PSDrive "Kablam" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\A ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Kablam:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

The `$cred` variable contains the credentials of a Local administrator user defined on Machine A which have been granted explicit full control over the `\\A\F$\Install path`

**When I try the similar command with my domain credentials it works fine.**

Why is this happening? Is there special permissions to grant to local users to allow them to mount Ps drives?

### FYI Why are we mounting a PSDrive ?

Deployment on Machine A are automated with Azure DevOps. Our deployment pipeline uses the [Copy Windows Machine File Task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops) that uses `New-PSDrive` under the hood.

Comment: Do you explicitly state that the user is a local user?  `.\username` instead of `username`

Comment: @sippybear yes actually the use is fully qualified with the machine's name `A\username`

Comment: Can you rule out permission problems by adding the mapped drive using `net use` or via the GUI (Windows Explorer)? Just in case you didn't forget to modify either of NTFS ACLs or SMB permissions.